# Where is the paper which present the correct formula for zeta function since i'm mixed?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I'm mixed when I accrossed the formula $(01)$ is presented in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1687-1847-2011-20)  (formula (6.1)) in the last page ) and formula $(02)$ is presented  [in this paper](http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/official_problem_description.pdf)  (page 2, formula 3) as shown below  , These formula were montioned  in the two papers that they are proved By Tchebeychev for $Re(s) >1$ , but they are not similar , I have tried to show that they are equivalent but i don't succeed , i don't know where is the problem ? Are they the same ? and if they are how do i show that they  are equivalent ?

$$\zeta(s)+1-\frac{1}{s-1}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \displaystyle(\frac{1}{-1+e^x}-\frac{1}{x})e^{-x}dt \tag{01}$$

$$\zeta(s)-1-\frac{1}{s-1}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty (\frac{1}{-1+e^x}-\frac{1}{x})e^{-x}x^{s-1}dt \tag{02}$$

Comment: When $s=2$ equation (01) is wrong.  The left side is positive and the right side is negative.  In any case, $\zeta$ is not so simple as that: a rational function plus a constant divided by the Gamma function.    But (02) seems numerically correct.  (Note, I assumed $dt$ means $dx$.)

Comment: I'm also confirmed for s=2 the formula (01) is wrong when i tried to show that limit (zeta(s)-1/s-1) is the Euler constant in the same time the RHS is negative, by the way i have used the substitustion e^(-x)=tan x, i accrossed this contradiction

Comment: @GEdgar, i'm confused how reviewers don't get attention to this wrong formula